# Startup Disk Creator not registering disk size

Tags: files, disk, startup-disk-creator, startup-disk

I'm trying to create a startup disk for ubuntu 15.04. I already have installed 15.04, but I need another copy.

It states that the disk has 2kb of storage size and it has none of that left, but I can burn files onto it and it states in other programs it has 4.7 GB of data space and none of it is used, what do I do?